# tabstop, softtabstop, shiftwidth - confused

Tags: softtabstop

I read through Vim documentation, blogs and SO questions on `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, `shiftwidth`, `expandtab`. I understood their purpose (may be not), but for all of the following setting, hitting `tab` key always moves cursor to right by `sw` number of whitespace (3 chars)

- `:set ts=5 sts=7 sw=3 noexpandtab`
- `:set ts=5 sts=7 sw=3 expandtab`
- `:set ts=5 sts=11 sw=3 noexpandtab`
- `:set ts=5 sts=11 sw=3 expandtab`

I used a text file to test. I have intentionally chosen prime values for each, to understand effect of each option.

Any idea why `tab` is picking `sw` instead of `tabstop` or `softtabstop`. I keep reading that `sts` is kind of 'wrapper' of `ts` where in between indentation that `tabstop` cannot reach, `sts` does.

I'm just not clear, from my experiments, when is each option used.

Comment: Try hitting tab more than once; what happens? What if sw is bigger than the others?

Comment: *"Any idea why tab is picking shiftwidth instead of tabstop or softtabstop?"* This shouldn't happen, a Tab key should always jump to the next `softtabstop` position, if that is set. Are you sure you don't have interference of a plug-in here? Check output of `:imap <Tab>` to see if your Tab key is remapped. Consider repeating this experiment on `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` to ensure you have no remappings or plugins loaded at the time.

Comment: @filbranden I opened the file with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N <file.txt>` and everything works as per Vim documentation. `<Tab>` gives me `sts` columns. I tested using all of above settings. However, when I opened `vim <file.txt>` and looked if `<Tab>` is remapped, it was not mapped to anything. Got `no mapping found`. Not sure why it is not working. If you want to write it as answer, I can accept

Comment: Yes I can write an answer, but I'm still puzzled at why "Tab" is not working as expected with your vimrc + plugins...  Does `:imap <Tab>` return nothing? How about `:imap <C-i>`? Does `:set cp?` tell you you're in `nocompatible` mode? What about `:set cpo?` does it have anything unusual in it? Do you use any plug-ins that typically remap "Tab" key, such as auto-completion plug-ins?

Comment: @filbranden here are results. `:imap <Tab> = No mapping found`, `:imap <C-i> = No mapping found`, `:set cp? = nocompatible`, `set cpo?` gives `cpoptions=aABceFs`. I read through all options and don't think there's interference with `<Tab>` behavior. I disabled all plugins in .vimrc and tried, but still the same `<Tab>` is using `sw=3`. Only thing that worked for me is opening files as `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N <file.txt>`. Vim version = 8.0

Comment: How about `:set indentexpr? indentkeys? cinkeys?` (or try the same with `&` instead of `?` to reset those to their defaults, see if that changes the behavior you're seeing...)

Comment: `set indentexpr?` gives `indentexpr=`, `set indentkeys?` gives `indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e`, `set cinkeys?` gives `cinkeys=0{,0},0),:,0#,!^F,o,O,e`. I'm reading up on these options. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: `cindent` is off btw. I also reset all these values, but behavior is same (`<Tab> == sw`)

Comment: Ah I think I found it! You must have [`'smarttab'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smarttab%27) on! Try `:set smarttab?`. I'll write an answer...

Comment: You are right. `smarttab` is on. I turned it off and now I see a `<Tab> == sts` at beginning of the line. This explains it's earlier behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea why "Tab" is picking `shiftwidth` instead of `tabstop` or `softtabstop`?

In your case, I believe it's because you were enabling [`'smarttab'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27smarttab%27) in your vimrc. This option makes "Tab" insert blanks according to `shiftwidth` when used in front of a line.

In normal situations, a Tab key jumps to the next `softtabstop` position, if that is set. If you repeat this experiment using `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` to ensure you have no interference from other settings, you should see the expected behavior.

Other than `'smarttab'`, there are other possibilities of configurations that would change the behavior of the "Tab" key.

It is possible that it's mapped by a plug-in (many completion plug-ins like to use "Tab" as a trigger for completion), in that case you can use `:imap <Tab>` to inspect whether there are any mappings for "Tab" in insert mode.

Other than that, there is [`'indentkeys'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27indentkeys%27) (if `'indentexpr'` is set) or [`'cinkeys'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cinkeys%27) that may include "Tab" as a special key triggering indentation behavior. "Tab" would show up as `^I` in those options (since Control-I is equivalent to Tab.)